# Syntax of NOT--exluding specific classes in sIFR

Tags: javascript, dom, sifr

I'm trying to sifr `ul#menu div`, but **exclude** `ul#menu div div`
I've experimented from the instructions on the Novemberborn Tricks page:

http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Tricks

But haven't been able to figure out the syntax. I can't seem to make it work.  Does anyone know if the EXCLUDE feature can be used on this without specifying a class or ID to be excluded?

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>
      <div>( sIFR THIS! )
         <a>Link 1</a>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div>( DON'T sIFR THIS! )
               <a>Link 1a</a>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ul#menu > li > div` as a selector.